# Laravel weird behavior when running behind an application gateway ( error 403 )

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I have an application that is running behind Azure Application Gateway, everything is working fine when I access the site normally but after idling for around 5 min, I start getting error 403 and it won't go away unless I remove the session cookies.

Currently I'm stuck and want to know what could cause this, if you have any clues please tell me.

I have this at the start of **index.php**

```
/**
 * Fix host standing behind proxy
 * And fix http schema  
 */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'];
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])){
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'];
}
```

and this at **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
{
    $Host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local' && $Host!=='10.166.4.4') {
        $url->forceScheme('https');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what causes this, i'm running my application behind **Azure Web Application Firewall** and sometimes Laravel generates a session cookie that contains something like V0x2bFB, the firewall treat this as trying sql injection and will block the request.

Refer to this issue for more details.

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/451